# Shadow below images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, website-design, color, photoshop-effects

I have this image that I got from slidesjs.com
[image]

It looks awesome when used as a frame, but I want to "elongate" it. Steps on how to accomplish this? I know it looks like a simple shadow, but the bottom shadow is darker. This is similar to this image:
[image]

Maybe someone has a link to a tutorial? I'm really focused on the frame though as the dark color isn't as apparent. It's more subtle.

Another reason why I want to do this, is that I want to change the shadow color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1**

1) Create the shape of the desired shadow. (I typically use variations of a circle)

2) Apply a 'Blur' filter to the shape you created.

3) Place the blurred shape layer beneath the subject you wish to apply this shadow to.

**Method 2**

1) Right click the layer of the subject you wish to apply shadow to.

2) Click blending options to open the layer effects dialogue.

3) Apply your shadow by clicking drop shadow.

Both methods have their benefits.